# strange behavior and crash

Tags: rosparam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am in the process of moving some system parameters from being hard coded to retrieving them from a parameter server. I am getting some strange outputs in by class constructor.

Here is the code:

```
// Ros Initalization
ros::NodeHandle n;

// getting system parameters from server
std::cout << "defining the vectors \n" << std::cout;
vector<float>
    cam_disp,
    cam_eul,
    imu_disp,
    imu_eul,
    imu_cov,
    lights;
std::cout << " defining the bool \n" << std::cout;
bool sim = false;
std::cout << " I am entering the while loop \n" << std::cout;
while(!n.hasParam("Camera/euler_angles") ||
    !n.hasParam("Camera/displacement") ||
    !n.hasParam("Imu/euler_angles") ||
    !n.hasParam("Imu/displacement") ||
    !n.hasParam("Is_simulation") ||
    !n.hasParam("Shipdeck/lights")){
        std::cout << " waiting for params " << std::endl;
        ros::Duration(0.5).sleep();
}
std::cout << " leaving  the while loop" << std::cout;
n.getParam("Camera/euler_angles", cam_eul);
n.getParam("Camera/displacement", cam_disp);
n.getParam("Imu/euler_angles", imu_eul);
n.getParam("Imu/displacement", imu_disp);
n.getParam("Is_simulating", sim);
n.getParam("Shipdeck/lights", lights);
if (sim == false){
    while(!n.hasParam("Imu/covariance"))
        ros::Duration(0.5).sleep();
    n.getParam("Imu/covariance", imu_cov);
}
else{
    while(!n.hasParam("Imu/covariance_sim"))
        ros::Duration(0.5).sleep();
    n.getParam("Imu/covariance_sim", imu_cov);
}
```

This is the output I'm seeing

```
defining the vectors 
0x190354 defining the bool 
0x190354 I am entering the while loop
```

I have no idea where the numbers are coming from, they aren't from anywhere else in the code. I don't believe that it's getting stuck in the while loop; I've run the code with an empty parameter sever and I've seen the waiting msg. Previously I was checking for the existence of each individual parameter and that worked fine. I moved to this setup because it's much easier to read.  Any help would be appreciated.

--

I should add that after the output I've posted above, the terminal becomes unresponsive. crt+c does nothing and I end up closing the window.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/213802/strange-behavior-and-crash/) by [holmes.kirby](https://answers.ros.org/users/20004/holmes.kirby/) on ROS Answers with karma: 20 on 2015-07-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is coming from you piping `std::cout` back into `std::cout`, as e.g. here:

```
std::cout << "defining the vectors \n" << std::cout;
```

I guess you mean

```
std::cout << "defining the vectors \n" << std::endl;
```

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2015-07-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [holmes.kirby](https://answers.ros.org/users/20004/holmes.kirby/) on 2015-07-15**:
that's embarrassing.  I should have more coffee before I code haha

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2015-07-15**:
always the best solution ;-)